Customized Multi-step wizard form using HTML CSS JS
I need help to customize the Multi-step wizard form where when I click on next button previous form should also be visible and when I click on prev button current form should hide.
Please help me I am stuck here. I have very limited experience in JavaScript.
Please find below the sample which I developed at least 70-80% but stuck in getting the remaining.


/**
 * Define a function to navigate betweens form steps.
 * It accepts one parameter. That is - step number.
 */
const navigateToFormStep = (stepNumber) => {
  /**
   * Hide all form steps.
   */
  document.querySelectorAll(".form-step").forEach((formStepElement) => {
    formStepElement.classList.add("d-none");
  });
  /**
   * Mark all form steps as unfinished.
   */
  document.querySelectorAll(".form-stepper-list").forEach((formStepHeader) => {
    formStepHeader.classList.add("form-stepper-unfinished");
    formStepHeader.classList.remove("form-stepper-active", "form-stepper-completed");
  });
  /**
   * Show the current form step (as passed to the function).
   */
  document.querySelector("#step-" + stepNumber).classList.remove("d-none");
  /**
   * Select the form step circle (progress bar).
   */
  const formStepCircle = document.querySelector('li[step="' + stepNumber + '"]');
  /**
   * Mark the current form step as active.
   */
  formStepCircle.classList.remove("form-stepper-unfinished", "form-stepper-completed");
  formStepCircle.classList.add("form-stepper-active");
  /**
   * Loop through each form step circles.
   * This loop will continue up to the current step number.
   * Example: If the current step is 3,
   * then the loop will perform operations for step 1 and 2.
   */
  for (let i = 0; i < stepNumber; i++) {
    /**
     * Select the form step circle (progress bar).
     */
    const formStep = document.querySelector('section[id=step-' + i + ']');
    //console.log(formStep);
    /**
     * Check if the element exist. If yes, then proceed.
     */
    if (formStep) {
      /**
       * Mark the form step as completed.
       */
      formStep.classList.remove("d-none");
      //formStep.classList.add("form-stepper-completed");
    }
  }

  for (let index = 0; index < stepNumber; index++) {
    /**
     * Select the form step circle (progress bar).
     */
    const formStepCircle = document.querySelector('li[step="' + index + '"]');
    //console.log(formStepCircle);
    /**
     * Check if the element exist. If yes, then proceed.
     */
    if (formStepCircle) {
      /**
       * Mark the form step as completed.
       */
      formStepCircle.classList.remove("form-stepper-unfinished", "form-stepper-active");
      formStepCircle.classList.add("form-stepper-completed");
    }
  }
};
/**
 * Select all form navigation buttons, and loop through them.
 */
document.querySelectorAll(".btn-navigate-form-step").forEach((formNavigationBtn) => {
  /**
   * Add a click event listener to the button.
   */
  formNavigationBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    /**
     * Get the value of the step.
     */
    const stepNumber = parseInt(formNavigationBtn.getAttribute("step_number"));
    /**
     * Call the function to navigate to the target form step.
     */
    navigateToFormStep(stepNumber);
  });
});
#multi-step-form-container {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.mx-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.pl-0 {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.button {
  padding: 0.3rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #4361ee;
  background-color: #4361ee;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submit-btn {
  border: 1px solid #0e9594;
  background-color: #0e9594;
}

.mt-3 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

.d-none1 {
  display: block;
}

.form-step {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 3rem;
  width: 155px;
  float: left;
}

.font-normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul.form-stepper {
  counter-reset: section;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

ul.form-stepper .form-stepper-circle {
  position: relative;
}

ul.form-stepper .form-stepper-circle span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.form-stepper-horizontal {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul.form-stepper>li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin-bottom 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin-bottom 0.4s;
  transition: margin-bottom 0.4s;
}

.form-stepper-horizontal>li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.form-stepper-horizontal li {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: start;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.form-stepper-horizontal li:not(:last-child):after {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  height: 1.5px;
  content: "";
  top: 25%;
}

.form-stepper-horizontal li:after {
  background-color: #000;
}

.form-stepper-horizontal li.form-stepper-completed:after {
  background-color: #70AD47;
}

.form-stepper-horizontal li:last-child {
  flex: unset;
}

ul.form-stepper li a .form-stepper-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
  text-align: center;
  /*    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-active .form-stepper-circle {
  /*
    background-color: #4361ee !important;
    color: #fff;
*/
  border: 2px solid #407BFF;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-active .label {
  color: #407BFF !important;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-active .form-stepper-circle:hover {
  /*
    background-color: #4361ee !important;
    color: #fff !important;
*/
  border: 2px solid #407BFF;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-unfinished .form-stepper-circle {
  background-color: #f8f7ff;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-completed .form-stepper-circle {
  /*
    background-color: #0e9594 !important;
    color: #fff;
*/
  border: 2px solid #70AD47;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-completed .label {
  color: #70AD47 !important;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-completed .form-stepper-circle:hover {
  /*
    background-color: #0e9594 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
*/
  border: 2px solid #70AD47;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-active span.text-muted {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.form-stepper .form-stepper-completed span.text-muted {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.form-stepper .label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.form-stepper a {
  cursor: default;
}
<div>

  <div id="multi-step-form-container">
    <!-- Form Steps / Progress Bar -->
    <ul class="form-stepper form-stepper-horizontal text-center mx-auto pl-0">
      <!-- Step 1 -->
      <li class="form-stepper-active text-center form-stepper-list" step="1">
        <a class="mx-2">
          <span class="form-stepper-circle">
                        <span></span>
          </span>
          <div class="label">Confirm Drawing</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <li class="form-stepper-unfinished text-center form-stepper-list" step="2">
        <a class="mx-2">
          <span class="form-stepper-circle text-muted">
                        <span></span>
          </span>
          <div class="label text-muted">Confirm Techsheet</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <li class="form-stepper-unfinished text-center form-stepper-list" step="3">
        <a class="mx-2">
          <span class="form-stepper-circle text-muted">
                        <span></span>
          </span>
          <div class="label text-muted">Confirm Quality Ch.</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!-- Step 4 -->
      <li class="form-stepper-unfinished text-center form-stepper-list" step="4">
        <a class="mx-2">
          <span class="form-stepper-circle text-muted">
                        <span></span>
          </span>
          <div class="label text-muted">Confirm PP sketch</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <!-- Step 5 -->
      <li class="form-stepper-unfinished text-center form-stepper-list" step="5">
        <a class="mx-2">
          <span class="form-stepper-circle text-muted">
                        <span></span>
          </span>
          <div class="label text-muted">Confirm 3D-Model</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Step Wise Form Content -->
    <form id="userAccountSetupForm" name="userAccountSetupForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <!-- Step 1 Content -->
      <section id="step-1" class="form-step">
        <h2 class="font-normal">Account Basic Details</h2>
        <!-- Step 1 input fields -->
        <div class="mt-3">
          Step 1 input fields goes here..
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="2">Next</button>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Step 2 Content, default hidden on page load. -->
      <section id="step-2" class="form-step d-none">
        <h2 class="font-normal">Social Profiles</h2>
        <!-- Step 2 input fields -->
        <div class="mt-3">
          Step 2 input fields goes here..
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="1">Prev</button>
          <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="3">Next</button>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Step 3 Content, default hidden on page load. -->
      <section id="step-3" class="form-step d-none">
        <h2 class="font-normal">Personal Details</h2>
        <!-- Step 3 input fields -->
        <div class="mt-3">
          Step 3 input fields goes here..
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="2">Prev</button>
          <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="4">Next</button>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Step 4 Content, default hidden on page load. -->
      <section id="step-4" class="form-step d-none">
        <h2 class="font-normal">Personal Details</h2>
        <!-- Step 3 input fields -->
        <div class="mt-3">
          Step 4 input fields goes here..
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="3">Prev</button>
          <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="5">Next</button>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Step 4 Content, default hidden on page load. -->
      <section id="step-5" class="form-step d-none">
        <h2 class="font-normal">Personal Details</h2>
        <!-- Step 3 input fields -->
        <div class="mt-3">
          Step 4 input fields goes here..
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="4">Prev</button>
          <button class="button submit-btn" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </section>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>



sample on codepen 

Please edit your question to include the code, rather than linking to an external site.

Code is too long that's why I have shared the codepen link

Can you simplify the code to the minimum needed to show the problem?

Please provide [mcve]. Simplify your code to just the problem you are trying to address.

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question is too broad.
